# What flexbox property would force vertical column of stacked items?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am teaching myself about flexbox layout and wish for my two "flex item" elements to be displayed one-above-the-other in a vertical column on screen widths below 600px.

My impression was that the "flex-direction:column" property below should take care of this, but it looks like I am misunderstanding the purpose or details of that property.

Can someone suggest a property that might allow this behavior?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html{background:gray; display:flex}
      .flex-container{background:brown; display:flex; height:100vh; width:600px; margin:auto; border:1px solid black;}
      .flex-item{background:white; width:250px; min-height:100px; margin:auto; font-size:14px;}
      @media (max-width:600px){
        .flex-container{width:100%; flex-direct:column;}
        .flex-item{width:100%; font-size:20px;}
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      This is a flex item.
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      This is a flex item. I expect it to move below the first on screens less than 600px;
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo: `flex-direct:column;` Correct the property name (`flex-direction`) then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, you have a typo in the flex-direction property. Try to replace "flex-direct:column;" with "flex-direction:column;".

I have tested your example and it helped, so your implession was correct.

Comment: Thanks - that did it!